# Setting the imageUrl for a VideoView in the XML layout file on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview, imageurl

I have an application that downloads JSON input from a web site that returns a URI to a picture or a video. I had no problem to get my MaterialCardView to display the pictures via an ImageView. My plan was to set an overlay VideoView that would be visible only when the specific item was a video type. Here is the XML of the 2 views:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture_image"
    android:layout_width="377dp"
    android:layout_height="429dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="84dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/nasa_pictures_list_id"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"

    app:imageUrl="@{picture.imgSrcUrl}"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/picture_title"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.47"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="191dp"
    tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="411dp"
    tools:src="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />
    <!-- android:visibility="@{picture.image ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"-->

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/picture_video"
    android:layout_width="377dp"
    android:layout_height="429dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="84dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/nasa_pictures_list_id"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"

    app:imageUrl="@{picture.imgSrcUrl}"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/picture_title"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.47"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="191dp"
    tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="411dp"
    tools:src="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />
    <!-- android:visibility="@{picture.video ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"-->
```

I commented out the android:visibility code for now.

My problem is that the VideoView has a compile error on the `app:imageUrl="@{picture.imgSrcUrl}"` that works just fine on the preceding ImageView. The error is:

`Cannot find a setter for <android.widget.VideoView app:imageUrl> that accepts parameter type 'java.lang.String'`

OK I get it, it does not like String.

- My question is what does it like and
- how do you specify it in a XML layout file?

Thanks page

Answer (score 0):

I have come to the conclusion that you can not do this via the XML file. I can not find a single example where this is being done. What I did do was adapt code that I found in the `SampleVideoView` in the Advanced Android Training that worked and can be found here; `https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-advanced/tree/master/SimpleVideoView`

First I created a Java class in in my app like this:

```
public class VideoViewAdapter {

    private  String VIDEO_SAMPLE =
            "https://images.all-free-download.com/footage_preview/mp4/rocket_launch_cape_caneveral_nasa_535.mp4";


    private Context mContext;
    private VideoView mVideoView;


    // Current playback position (in milliseconds).
    private int mCurrentPosition = 0;

    // Tag for the instance state bundle.
    private static final String PLAYBACK_TIME = "play_time";

    public void initVideo(Context context, VideoView videoView) {
        // Set up the media controller widget and attach it to the video view.
        mVideoView = videoView;
        MediaController controller = new MediaController(context);
        controller.setMediaPlayer(mVideoView);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(controller);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void initializePlayer(VideoView videoView,String url, int position) {

        if(url!=null) VIDEO_SAMPLE = url;
        if(position!=0) mCurrentPosition = position;
        mVideoView = videoView;
        // Buffer and decode the video sample.
        Uri videoUri = getMedia(VIDEO_SAMPLE);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);

        // Listener for onPrepared() event (runs after the media is prepared).
        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(
                new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

                        // Restore saved position, if available.
                        if (mCurrentPosition > 0) {
                            mVideoView.seekTo(mCurrentPosition);
                        } else {
                            // Skipping to 1 shows the first frame of the video.
                            mVideoView.seekTo(1);
                        }

                        // Start playing!
                        mVideoView.start();
                    }
                });

        // Listener for onCompletion() event (runs after media has finished
        // playing).
        mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(
                new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,
                                R.string.toast_message,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // Return the video position to the start.
                        mVideoView.seekTo(0);
                    }
                });
    }


    // Release all media-related resources. In a more complicated app this
    // might involve unregistering listeners or releasing audio focus.
    public void releasePlayer() {
        mVideoView.stopPlayback();
    }

    // Get a Uri for the media sample regardless of whether that sample is
    // embedded in the app resources or available on the internet.
    private Uri getMedia(String mediaName) {
        if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(mediaName)) {
            // Media name is an external URL.
            return Uri.parse(mediaName);
        } else {
            // Media name is a raw resource embedded in the app.

            return Uri.parse("android.resource://" + mContext.getPackageName() +
                    "/raw/" + mediaName);
        }
    }
}
```

This provided me with a view adapter that I could instantiate at the top of my MainActivity like this:

**in Kotlin now:**

```
.
.
.
lateinit var VIDEOADAPTOR: VideoViewAdapter
.
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        .
        .
        .
        VIDEOADAPTOR = VideoViewAdapter()
```

Then in the Fragment class file for the layout fragment. I placed the following code in the RecyclerView.Adapter class under the onBindViewHolder override.

```
class DailyPictureAdapter(val callback: PictureClick) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DailyPictureViewHolder>() {

.
.
.
/**
     * Called by RecyclerView to display the data at the specified position. This method should
     * update the contents of the {@link ViewHolder#itemView} to reflect the item at the given
     * position.
     */
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DailyPictureViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.viewDataBinding.also {
            it.picture = pictures[position]
            it.pictureCallback = callback
            if(pictures[position].isVideo) {
                VIDEOADAPTOR.initVideo(context, it.pictureVideo)
                VIDEOADAPTOR.initializePlayer(it.pictureVideo,it.pictureVideo.pictures[position].imgSrcUrl, 0)

            }
        }
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{ callback.onClick(pictures[position])}

    }

}
```

This worked it played the video in the Video View as part of the Recycler View. Nice but....

My issue with this would be memory use. For my app that has 15 to 25 records at a time with only a few of them being Videos this did not present an issue. However if this was a list of Videos I think we would find a memory issue very quickly.

I could not find a good place to release the resources as they scrolled out of view. If someone can comment on that please do.